# finding redirects in python using only the final url

Tags: python, html, redirect

Is there a way in which you can find which websites redirect to a certain site. for example domain.co/ domain.tk/ domain.us all redirect to domain.com. Is there a way using only domain.com to find domain.co/ domain.tk/ domain.us. (using python)

Answer (score 1):

You could use requests module http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://github.com')
if r.history:
    print "Request was redirected"
    print r.history
else:
    print "Request was not redirected"
```

Comment: not really what i was looking for. I was looking for a way to start with the end url and work backwards to find the sites that redirect to the end site.